# Why page is refreshing after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one event. If it is blur then page is not refreshing but if it is click event then page is reloading. What is the reason for the same.

```
$('#weeklygeneratebtn').on('click',function(){
    $('#store_name').on('blur',function(){
        var store_id = $("input[name=store_id]").val();
        alert($(this).attr("data-indent"));
        var category = '';
        var flag;
        if($(this).data("indent") == "sundry"){
            category = '235';
            flag = 1;
        }
        if(flag== 1){
            $.ajax({ url: 'lib/function.php',
                data: {action: 'getStoreSupplyItems', 
                       id:store_id, 
                       indent:1, 
                       category:category},
                success: function(output) {
                     //alert(output);
                     $('#response').html(output);
                }     
            });
        }
```

This is my code.If select the click function after ajax call the page is refreshing. But if I select the blur function the page is not reloading. My first doubt is what is the reason for reloading and my second question is what should I do for not reloading in click case.

```
<button id="weeklyindentbtn" style="width:120px" class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all action-button ui-button-text-only" data-role="button">&nbsp;&nbsp;Generate</button>
```

Comment: You don't seem to disable the click default event from occurring. See https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: can you show us your html of the link/button you click on ?  

the id "weeklygeneratebtn" you have gave to is <a> tag or button ?

Answer (score 3):

If your button is an "input" element with a type of "submit" then in the Javascript click handler you need to pass the "event" parameter in the function call and then include the preventdefault function, like this:

```
$("#weeklygeneratebtn").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); ... });
```

This will stop the normal behaviour (i.e. a postback) from occurring.

If your button is a "button" element then you can add the "button" type to it to prevent postbacks, like this:

```
<button type="button" id="weeklygeneratebutton">Generate</button>
```

Comment: @django Ok so it looks like you need to add `type="button"` to your button definition, as I've suggested above. Otherwise it will default to `type="submit"`, which will cause a postback

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing the click event from propagating and doing the default behavior of the browser.  For example:

```
$('#weeklygeneratebtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do stuff
});
```